# Group controllers in same tag swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, swagger

I have 2 controllers with different api versions but same swagger tag

```
@RequestMapping("/v1")
@Tag(name = "controller")
public class ControllerV1 {
    v1 GET/POST/PUT
}
```

```
@RequestMapping("/v2")
@Tag(name = "controller")
public class ControllerV2 {
    v2 GET/POST/PUT
}
```

Is there a way to group endpoints by controller in one tag but leaving order of http methods in each controller?

I want something like:

- v1 GET
- v1 PUT
- v2 GET
- v2 PUT

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is make the version number a part of the tag like @Tag("v1/controller")
This will achieve a nice grouping.